# Does Windows 8 use English during its first boot steps?

Tags: windows-8, boot, language

I live in China. I cannot read Chinese. I am thinking about buying a new laptop soon.

What does each screen prompt from me (or for me) during the first boot? Is there a resource you can point me to on the Internet that covers this issue? Or does Windows 8 prompt you for the language you'd like to use like the Mac does?

Comment: You *could* ask one of the Chinese people around you to translate it for you.

Comment: If you cannot read Chinese, format the laptop, and install an english version of Windows 8.

Comment: To the first response, yes I could do that, but it doesn't actually address my question. To the second, then I know I would not have most or even any of the actual drivers needed for the hardware. I have also investigated enough to know that Windows 8 does away with only the Ultimate editions providing multi-language support. Therefore, once I get past the initial boot, I can just change the language to English. I know I'm new here and all, but please be a "superuser" and give me the guidance I'm asking for and if you do not know the answer, do not bother responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first launch Windows 8 or 8.1 it should give you an option to choose your language. If you're going to be using the pre-installed OS, you just choose a language, make some personalizations such as setting theme and background colors. Similar to that is installing a fresh copy of Windows 8 or 8.1.

[Follow this guide](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/ss/windows-8-clean-install-part-1.htm) if you're going to be installing a fresh copy of Windows 8 or 8.1.

If you don't want to go through the hassle of installing a fresh copy and there is no option to change languages, then simply install the chinese version by following a video or guide and install the language pack from inside Windows. [Here is a quick video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4xSOzAVEeo) on how to add languages.

Comment: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."